# pandas multiple rows to single row with multiple columns on 2 indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a pandas dataframe from:

```
ID ID_ver type count price discount
1  1      a    4     100   20
1  1      b    3     50    0
1  2      a    4     100   30
1  2      b    3     50    5
1  2      c    1     70    10
```

to:

```
ID ID_ver count_a price_a discount_a count_b price_b discount_b count_c price_c discount_c
```

I have 10 different possible types and thousands of ID, with up to 10 versions each.

I tried:

```
df.drop_duplicates()
df.set_index(['ID','ID_VER','TYPE'])[['count','PRICE','DISCOUNT']].unstack()
```

but getting the error:

> Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape.

As much as I tried, don't understand why.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas` is using unique values for the index. You set a triple index, and it seems like some observations would have the same three values if you do so. As a result, `pandas` is throwing an error.

I can reproduce your error changing one value of your example, to make it so two observations have the same index values:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()

df.iloc[2, 1] = 1
```

Observations 0 and 2 now have the same (future) index values, which will throw an error.

```
   ID  ID_ver type  count  price  discount
0   1       1    a      4    100        20 # 1, 1, a
1   1       1    b      3     50         0
2   1       1    a      4    100        30 # 1, 1, a
3   1       2    b      3     50         5
4   1       2    c      1     70        10
```

```
df.set_index(['ID','ID_ver','type'])[['count','price','discount']].unstack()
```

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
pd.pivot_table(your_df, values=['count', 'price', 'discount'], index=['ID','ID_ver'], columns='type')
```

If you want to flatten from the multi-index columns:

```
your_df.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() for col in your_df.columns.values]
```

To flatten the row multi-index:

```
your_df = your_df.reset_index()
```

Edit: changed to pivot_table, added column flattening, row flattening

Comment: Thanks! considering the problem Nicolas Gervais pointed out, this was part of the solution.