# Python : Pandas pivot table for multiple columns at once which has duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot

have a pandas dataframme with columns name , school and marks

```
name  school  marks

tom     HBS     55
tom     HBS     55
tom     HBS     14
mark    HBS     28
mark    HBS     19
lewis   HBS     88
```

How to transpose and convert into like this

```
name  school  marks_1 marks_2 marks_3

tom     HBS     55     55       14
mark    HBS     28     19
lewis   HBS     88
```

tried this:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='name', values='marks', columns='school') \
    .reset_index() \
    .rename_axis(None, axis=1)

print(df)
```

```
df = df.pivot('name','marks','school')
```

checked these links

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798934/pandas-long-to-wide-reshape-by-two-variables
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62391419/pandas-group-by-and-convert-rows-into-multiple-columns
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60698109/pandas-multiple-rows-to-single-row-with-multiple-columns-on-2-indexes
```

getting this error due to duplicate values. how to handle if duplicate exists and we have to keep them

```
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `set_index` and `unstack` with `groupby` and `cumcount`:

```
df_out = df.set_index(['name',
                       'school',
                       df.groupby(['name','school'])\
           .cumcount() +1]).unstack()
df_out.columns = [f'{i}_{j}' for i, j in df_out.columns]
df_out = df_out.reset_index()
df_out
```

Output:

```
    name school  marks_1  marks_2  marks_3
0  lewis    HBS     88.0      NaN      NaN
1   mark    HBS     28.0     19.0      NaN
2    tom    HBS     55.0     55.0     14.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The `cumcount` function allows one to create unique indices before pivoting. This builds on the same idea as @ScottBoston; however, the `pivot` function is used here:

```py
index = ['name', 'school']

                  # create an extra column for uniqueness          
temp = (df.assign(counter = df.groupby(index)
                              .cumcount()
                              .add(1)
                              .astype(str))
          .pivot(index = index, columns = 'counter')
        )

# flatten the columns
temp.columns = temp.columns.map('_'.join)

temp.reset_index()

    name school  marks_1  marks_2  marks_3
0  lewis    HBS     88.0      NaN      NaN
1   mark    HBS     28.0     19.0      NaN
2    tom    HBS     55.0     55.0     14.0
```

Alternatively, you could use the [pivot_wider](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_wider) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), which is syntactic sugar around `pd.pivot`, with some helpers:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
(df.assign(counter = df.groupby(index)
                       .cumcount()
                       .add(1))                              
   .pivot_wider(index = index, 
                names_from = 'counter', 
                names_sep = '_')
)

    name school  marks_1  marks_2  marks_3
0  lewis    HBS     88.0      NaN      NaN
1   mark    HBS     28.0     19.0      NaN
2    tom    HBS     55.0     55.0     14.0
```